# R : "weights = varIdent" helps to deal with unbalanced classes in a linear model?

Tags: r, statistics, data-modeling, anova, hypothesis-test

I want to fit a linear mixed model (because I have repeated measures over time).

```
LM.fit <- lme(VR ~ Group * Time + Age + sexe + study,
             random = ~1|subject,
             method = "REML",
             na.action = na.omit,
             data = Data)
```

I check the assumptions (which is ok I think ?!)

[image]

**BUT I have unbalanced classes in Group : Subgroup1 have 80 samples and Subgroup2 have 20 samples.**.

```
LM.fit <- lme(VR ~ Group * Time + Age + sexe + study,
             random = ~1|subject,
             weights = varIdent(form = ~1|Group),
             method = "REML",
             na.action = na.omit,
             data = Data)
```

**weights = varIdent(form = ~1|Group)** I heard that adding this line can help accounting for unequal variances across groups and unbalanced classes. **Can someone help me to know why and how?**

If you have other methods, i am listening